# How many pairs of positive constants $a, b$ exist such that $P(a < X < b) = 0.95$, where $X$ has a chi-squared distribution?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

$X$ is a chi-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom (sum of the squares of $n$ $N(0,1)$ variables). How many pairs of positive constants $a,b$ exist such that

$$ P(a < X < b) = 0.95 $$

I'm not really sure how to go about this - I know it can be done using the c.d.f of a chi-squared distribution but I don't think we're supposed to use this method, given that we haven't covered it yet.

Any hints would be appreciated :)

Comment: Given the value of $a$, we can find the value $b(a)$ as a function of $a$ such that the probability is $0.95$

Comment: Because of the nature of this distribution (continuous monotonically increasing CDF) For any $a>0$ with $P(X\leq a)<0.05$ there is a unique $b>0$ with $P(a<X<b)=0.95$.

Comment: No. $P(X\leq a)<0.05$ gives $P(a<X)>0.95$ and that is what you need here.

Comment: Sorry yeah, my bad @drhab ! If you leave your comment as an answer I can mark it correct :)

Comment: Infinitely many, because the support of the density function is continuous and unbounded.

Answer (score 2):

The CDF of the mentioned distribution is continuous and is monotonically increasing on $(0,\infty)$.

Consequently for *every* $a>0$ with $P(X\leq a)<0.05$ or equivalently $P(X>a)>0.95$ a unique $b>a>0$ exists such that $P(a<X<b)=0.95$.

Combining the mentioned properties of the CDF with $F_X(0)=0$ we find that the set $\{a\in(0,\infty)\mid P(X\leq a)<0.05\}$ is uncountably infinite.